# "Could not find table" after running db:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In the local dev machine,

1. I added a model with `rails g model Place title:string location:string`
2. Added some default data in `seeds.rb`
3. Ran `rake db:setup`

The feature was working correctly, So in the server which had a running rails app,

1. I `git pull`ed the sources without stopping the running rails app
2. Ran `rake db:setup`
3. The table and data were created when checked in the db console.
4. Made a request to the app but an error occured: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid "Could not find table(place)`
5. Ran `rake db:migrate`, then everything went well.

*What might have caused the `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error to happen in step 4? Is it always necessary to run `db:migrate` after running `db:setup`?*

---

Rails version: 4.2.3 both in local and server.

Running `rake db:migrate:status` shows following output.

```
Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     000             ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150721031229  Create places
```

DB console shows following output.

```
sqlite> select * from schema_migrations;
0
20150721031229
```

---

Edit: added full backtrace of error in step 4

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 13.2ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'places'):
  app/models/place.rb:47:in `get_random_place'
  app/models/place.rb:29:in `handle'
  app/controllers/message_controller.rb:27:in `handle'


  Rendered /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (16.6ms)
```

app/models/place.rb:47

```
def self.get_random_place
    offset = rand(Place.count)
    place = Place.offset(offset).first
    place
end
```

Comment: Post full backtrace of step 4 error

Comment: @RAJ I've added full backtrace of step 4 error.

Comment: Can you try `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20150721031229` then `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20150721031229`. If still faces issue, post content of your migration file

Comment: @RAJ there are no issues now, after I've ran rake db:migrate(step 5). I was just curious as to why it did happen in the first place.

Comment: Somehow, your migration version got added to `schema_migrations`, may be, you ran `rake db:migrate` before it had required content or so.